# How do i add another Table ROW at the end of my loop.

Tags: php, html

I would like to add a row, after the loop, the number of rows before the LAST row is random based on the user's orders. so for example the user ordered 10, i would like to add another row, to the list. even if the order is 3 there would still be another row at the end.

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row['prod_name']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['quantity']."</td>";
echo "<td>₱".number_format(($row['price']*$row['quantity']),2)."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
        if($row['carrier']=="LBC"){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Shippment Option Chosen: ".$row['carrier']."</td>";
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "<td>₱250.00</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
            }
    }
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Here, i made it create another row, but it creates a row after each row, i just need to add 1 row at the end of the table. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm Why not just add a new query? I fixed your codes. and added these.

```
$qryx = "SELECT DISTINCT customers.serial,customers.name,customers.payment,customers.carrier,customers.tracking_no, orders.date, order_detail.productid, order_detail.quantity, order_detail.price, order_detail.orderid, inventory.prod_name 
        FROM customers 
        RIGHT JOIN orders on customers.serial=orders.serial 
        RIGHT JOIN order_detail on orders.serial=order_detail.orderid 
        LEFT JOIN inventory on order_detail.productid=inventory.prod_id
        where customers.email='{$_SESSION['email']}' 
        AND order_detail.orderid='{$_REQUEST['orderid']}'
        GROUP BY customers.carrier";

$resulty = @mysql_query($qryx);
while ($rowz=mysql_fetch_array($resulty)){

    if($rowz['carrier']=="LBC"){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Shippment Option Chosen: ".$rowz['carrier']."</td>";
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "<td>₱250.00</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
```

I changed the name of the qry, result, and row. and added DISTINCT and GROUP BY to remove redundancy.

Comment: No problem! Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a line right before your

```
echo "</table>";
```

line, but after the closing bracket before it. That last closing bracket is where your loop ends. It should look like this:

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row['prod_name']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['quantity']."</td>";
echo "<td>₱".number_format(($row['price']*$row['quantity']),2)."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
        if($row['carrier']=="LBC"){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Shippment Option Chosen: ".$row['carrier']."</td>";
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "<td>₱250.00</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
            }
    }
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>LAST LINE...</td>";
  echo "<td></td>";
  echo "<td></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: but i am using the $row['carrier'] which will be called in the loop. how do i fix that?

Comment: Your loop is running through the sql results. What sort of data do you need to display in your last column?

Comment: A condition statement, If $row['carrier'] which is from the database, if the carrier is LBC then it would display another row.

Comment: from your code, the $row variable is only available within the loop. I dont think you can keep using $row outside the loop, unless you saved the last $row variable into something else while inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysqli_num_rows to get the no. of rows. Then you can add a counter in the while loop. When the counter = mysqli_num_rows, you can echo the row you wanted to echo at last

Example:

```
$totalrows=mysqli_num_rows($result);
$counter=1;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    //echo the row data
if($counter==$totalrows)
    {
    //echo the extra row which you wanted.
    }
}
echo "</table>";
```